# How to replace all string in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In postgresql database have one function `btrim(string text [, characters text])`.

For examples

```
btrim('xwxpostsqlwwx', 'wx')
```

In this function return value postsql.

Like this I need to do in SQL Server 2005. Is there any similar builtin function available in SQL Server?

Comment: I need to check if 'M' -> 'Male' like 'F'->Female...

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE, SUBSTRING,CHARINDEX 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any exact equivalent, but you should be able to achieve the same results using SQLServer's [Regular Expression functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such a *built-in* function, but you can create your own if you like. You can find an example of a function doing exactly what you want [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) (at the bottom of the page).